# VB file compression in VS2013

Tags: vb.net, file, visual-studio-2013, compression

I came across [an article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346377/vb-file-compression-in-vs2013) on implementing .zip VB file compression in VS2013 but have a snag in implementing it.

When I get to the line `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory`, I get an error in VS that .ZipFile is not a member of ".Compression".

Here’s the code for my command button (using user3688529's code) called zipButton and listbox called filesListBox:

```
Private Sub zipButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles zipButton.Click
    'Button click events.
    'Start backup.
    Dim PjtPath As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim ZipLocal As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim ZipNetwk As String = TextBox3.Text
    Static Dim StartPath As String
    Static Dim ZipPath As String
    For Each a As String In filesListBox.SelectedItems()
        'Dim PjtName As String = ListBox1.SelectedItems(a).ToString
        Dim PjtName As String = a
        Dim ZipExt As String = Format(Now, " yyyy-MM-dd @ HHmm") & ".zip"
        If TextBox2.Text = String.Empty Then
            StartPath = PjtPath & "\" & PjtName
            ZipPath = PjtPath & "\" & PjtName & ZipExt
        ElseIf TextBox2.Text <> String.Empty Then
            StartPath = PjtPath & "\" & PjtName
            ZipPath = ZipLocal & "\" & PjtName & ZipExt
        End If
        System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory _
        (StartPath, ZipPath, IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Optimal, True)
        If TextBox3.Text <> String.Empty Then
            Dim ZipCopy As String = ZipNetwk & "\" & PjtName & ZipExt
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(ZipPath, ZipCopy)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Is there some module I need to include in order for the .ZipFle member to be accessable?

Comment: Which .NET Framework version are you using? ZipFile was only added in Framework 4.5

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. I'm updated through .Net Framework v4.5.1 Multi-targeting pack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to add a reference to System.IO.Compression.FileSystem in your project references.
"Project -> Add Reference".  Under Framework, find System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added the reference as you suggested and it cleared the error. When I attempted to run the program I received the runtime error: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"